# Cropping Images from pickerView

Tags: swift, image, resize, uipickerview, crop

I get an image from pickerView and need to crop it to 500x500px.
How can I do this?

I am using Swift 2.2. I didn't find any framework to resize or crop to square with default size.

**UPDATE**
My code :

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

        imageView.image = pickedImage  

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0.7)
```

I need to crop this **pickedImage**

**UPDATE #2.** 
khuong291's solution helped me, now it's 500x500px but imageView.image becomes black screen, help, please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For image manipulation, I use a library called Toucan.
https://github.com/gavinbunney/Toucan

You'll find a crop example on the home page, it's as easy as:

```
let croppedImage = Toucan(image: sourceImage).resize(CGSize(width: 500, height: 500), fitMode: Toucan.Resize.FitMode.Crop).image
```

Comment: Look :

let croppedImage = Toucan.Resize.resizeImage(pickedImage, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))

print("image size", croppedImage.size)

Output : 730, 500 (only one side is equal to 500px)

Comment: if I use with mask - it's okay, but i don't need mask

Comment: I think your forgot the "fitMode" part:
fitMode: Toucan.Resize.FitMode.Crop


That's what makes the crop.


(I just realised you didn't notice there's a horizontal scroll in my sample code, an only copied the visible part)